# How to import project from git in AIDE?

Tags: git, bitbucket, aide-ide, android-ide

I've created private repo on bitbucket and added public key from `PuTTY Key Generator`.

Using TortoiseGIT I've managed to push my project from PC and then I wanted to pull it from AIDE. So I've created .ssh folder on /sdcard and made sure that this location is in `Git Source Control -> .ssh directory` settings and I copied there files exported from `PuTTY Key Generator` (private and public, just to be sure)

Then I've choosen `Clone Git repository`, provided URL and tried to clone. There was an error: `Git clone failed: session is down`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've figured it out. In case someone gets the same problem here's the solution

After generating a key in `PuTTY Key Generator` save files in the following way:

1. public key:

   - copy content of `Public key for pasting into OpenSSH authorized_keys file`
   - paste into notepad and save as `filename.pub`
2. private key:

   - `Conversions` tab -> `Export OpenSSH key`
   - save file as `id_rsa`
3. copy those two files to `/sdcard/.ssh` and it should work

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Vw7b.png) an image of private key export in case someone is confused.